# How to build a join clause on multiple columns in pyspark with an OR clause?

Tags: join, pyspark

Given

```
  valuesA = [('A','B'),('C','D'),('E','A'),('F','G')]
  TableA = spark.createDataFrame(valuesA,['column1','column2'])

  valuesB = [('A', 'Good'), ('D', 'Bad')]
  TableB = spark.createDataFrame(valuesB,['value','condition'])

  columns = ["column1", "column2"]
  join_column = "value"
```

I want to write a join that loops over the columns and checks for or logic.

e.g.

```
# The problem here is this results in an AND clause
return(TableA.join(TableB,
                    [col(column) == col(join_column) for column in columns],
                    inner))
```

The ideal result is

```
| column1 | column 2 | condition |
|---------|----------|-----------|
|   A     |     B    |   Good    |
|   C     |     D    |   Bad     |
|   E     |     A    |   Good    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the join on multiple columns by generating the join condition and applying it on the dataframes by using expr function

## Using the sql views and sql statements

```
columns = TableA.columns 
join_column = "value"


from pyspark.sql.functions import *
temp1 = TableA.createOrReplaceTempView("Temper1")
temp2 = TableB.createOrReplaceTempView("Temper2")
required_condition = " or ".join(  "{} == {}".format(x,join_column ) for x in columns)
print(required_condition)

spark.sql("select * from Temper1").show()
spark.sql("select * from Temper2").show()
print("required_condition is ", required_condition)
spark.sql(" select * from Temper1 join Temper2 on {} ".format(required_condition))
```

## Using the expr function

```
required_condition = " or ".join(  "{} == {}".format(x,join_column ) for x in columns)
TableA.join( TableB, expr(required_condition), "inner" ).show()
```